# How To Add 'Likes' On The Main Page For Multiple Objects With Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an Ajax Like/Dislike button that works for the product detail page. However, I want to add it on the main page, where multiple products are listed. Here is what I currently have in the **models.py**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
    ...

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


    def is_liked(self, request):
        return self.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()
```

**views.py**:

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    return render(request, 'product/home.html', {'product': products})


def detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, product_id=product_id)
    is_liked = False
    if product.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': product.total_likes()
    }
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', context)


def like_product(request):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    if product.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        product.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        product.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
        'total_likes': product.total_likes()
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('product/likes.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

**home.html**:

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {% for product in product.all %}
      {% if product.featured %}
        ...
        <div id="like-section-{{ product.id }}">{{ product.total_likes }} Like{{ product.total_likes|pluralize }}
          <form action="{% url 'like_product' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {% if product.is_liked %}
              <button type="submit" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-like btn-danger">Dislike</button>
            {% else %}
              <button type="submit" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-like btn-primary">Like</button>
            {% endif %}
          </form>
        </div>
        ...
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the status of Like/Dislike button is not being saved (When I press "Like", button changes to "Dislike" and the like is being recorded. However after I reload the page button changes back to "Like"). It seems like there is an issue in the `is_liked` function inside the `Product` class. Not sure how to fix that. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `product.is_liked` receives `request` as parameter, but you are not passing it!?, I would change it to receive the user id and pass the user id as `product.is_liked(request.user.id)` but I don't even know if this is valid in django

Comment: It makes me wonder if you are not receiving an error by calling a method with to few parameters

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not valid in Django. I have no errors, just "Like" button is not working properly. Maybe there is completely different way how to solve this? Without is_liked function? TY!